# Buld icon and content assit in Eclipse pages?

Tags: eclipse, content-assist

Sometimes a little bulb icon appears in the current edit field in Eclipse. Hint says "Content Assist Available".

[image]

What does this bulb mean?

(P.S. I would not ask if Ctrl-Space invoked some content assistance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is supposed to mean that content assist is available. However as you have found it does not seem to function on this field in the extension point editor.